# How can i compare a NSString with two other NSStrings

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

My problem is that i have a NSString and i have to compare it with two other NSStrings.

How can i compare NSStrings like:

```
if(a == (b || c))
```

My resolution for this isn't fine yet (but works) :

```
NSString *a = @"myfirststring";
NSString *b = @"mysecondstring";
if([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s", MethodThatReturnsChar*] isEqual:a] || [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",MethodThatReturnsChar*] isEqual:b])
{
}
```

The problem is that i have to call MethodThatReturnsChar* two times, that isn't necessary, is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> that isn't necessary, is it?

Exactly, it's completely superfluous. That's why the C language has variables... Also, don't abuse `- [NSString stringWithFormat:]`. Furthermore, use `isEqualToString:` for comparison:

```
NSString *a = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:someCharPtr];
if ([a isEqualToString:b] || [a isEqualToString:c]) {
    DoStuff();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign that string to a variable, and then compare it with the other strings

```
    NSString *a = @"myfirststring";
    NSString *b = @"mysecondstring";
    NSString *stringIAmComparing = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s", MethodThatReturnsChar*];
    if([stringIAmComparing isEqualToString:a] || [stringIAmComparing isEqualToString:b])
    {
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your "MethodThatReturnsChar*" into another NSString using

```
NSString* stringToCompare = [NSString stringWithCString:yourCString encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

and then compare:

```
if([stringToCompare isEqualToString:a] || [stringToCompare isEqualToString:b])
```

Hope that helps.